# Laptop Audio: Buzzing sound while charging and using Headphone Jack or USB C adapter

Tags: laptop, audio, usb-c, noise, usb-audio

Whenever I plug-in USB-C PD Charger, I hear a constant buzz in my earphone irrespective of whether I use Headphone Jack on Laptop or I use Apple [USB-C to 3.5 mm Headphone Jack Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MU7E2AM/A/usb-c-to-35-mm-headphone-jack-adapter).

I am surprised as I thought that the whole purpose of using USB-C adapter was to completely isolate these kinds of noise!

The moment I touch my laptop (surface is made of Aluminum alloy) the buzzing sound goes away (as my body acts as a ground!

Is this because the build quality of laptop not good? Or is there a defect in my laptop hardware?

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state, the buzz indicates that there is AC mains leaking into the audio, and your test of touching the case, which stopped the hum, confirms that. Note that your touching the case did not ground it, but rather *put your body and the headphones at the same potential as the case*... which could be problematic, in reason 2. below.

There are two likely ways that 50- or 60-Hz could get into circuits from the charger:

1. There can be capacitive coupling in a *non*grounded power supply, either from the mains hot lead, or from high-speed pulses in the switching power supply. That is trivial, and can easily be remedied by adding a 0.1 µF, 300 V capacitor from the third (ground) pin of the mains socket to the PC shell, with a 270 kΩ resistor in parallel to dissipate any charge built up on the capacitor. That is what I did for a Toshiba laptop, which has been working well for years since that wire was added.
2. There *could* be actual mains current flowing from the power supply due to an internal short -- effectively putting your body at 120 or 240 VAC! If you were to touch both the case and a grounded object (e.g., refrigerator, washing machine or water pipe), the result could be fatal.

To check if there is *dangerous* leakage, connect a multimeter on its AC voltaage range from the USB-C outer shell to ground, *with a 0.1 µF cap mentioned above across the meter* to lessen any *minor* leakage current (modern high-impedance multimeter are too sensitive, otherwise). If the meter indicates more than 10 volts, with the capacitor bypassing it, the power supply is, indeed, defective and could cause electrocution. Replace it. **N.B.: Use care connecting the meter. *First* connect the leads, *then* plug in the supply! Do not touch the wires while the supply is in the wall socket.**

Comment: Is USB-C to Headphone Jack not supposed to solve this problem? I use USB 4 to charge my laptop.

Comment: As long as there is a **physical** electrical connection, AC mains-frequency signals have the potential (NPI) to enter. Use Bluetooth, to avoid a ground loop.

Comment: So, using USB-C Audio does not help in isolating the noise, as claimed by most companies that have ditched headphone jack.

Comment: The advantage of using USB for audio is ta avoid the cost of the connector, it's through-hole, and for rugged devices, gaskets. Advantages to the *manufacturer*. Haven't heard the buzz about "improved audio".

Comment: In the first sentence you concluded that it is AC current leaking. Can't it be due to DC? I am not sure how did you conclude this. If possible please explain. Also, can we conclude that there is no fault with the laptop, but the power supply is to blame (without doing the multimeter test that you mentioned). Since, I only sometimes feel a mild tingle in my fingers when I touch the charging laptop, can we conclude that leaking AC current is not dangerous?

Comment: DC does not "buzz".

Comment: Also, can we conclude that there is no fault with the laptop, but the power supply is to blame (without doing the multimeter test that you mentioned). Since, I only sometimes feel a mild tingle in my fingers when I touch the charging laptop, can we conclude that leaking AC current is not dangerous?

Comment: Yes, you've already tested it with your body, and live. BTW, I am writing this answer from an ancient Toshiba with a capacitor and resistor connected from the power supply plug outside shell to the wall outlet ground. It's power supply has only a two-prong plug, and caused that *tingly* feeling when touching the laptop case. Exact parts values are *not* critical, but don't go below 270 kΩ for the resistor.

Comment: So we can conclude that there is no fault with the laptop, but the power supply is to blame (without doing the multimeter test that you mentioned). I am asking as I can return the defective charger to the company.